# Multiple UICOLLECTION View in a single view controller in iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionreusableview

I want to put more than one uicollectionview in one view controller i have successfully put  it in storyboard as well as i have code that in .m file like below.

```
 -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
 {  

if (_collectionview.tag==2) {


Cell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];


 [cell.image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.104:808/Images/Image1.jpg"]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"0.jpg"]];
    cell.label.text = [[recipes valueForKey:@"name"]objectAtIndex:0];


return cell;

}

if(_collectionview.tag==1)
{
    Cell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:jerryCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];


    [cell.image1 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20121123214954/tomandjerry/images/a/a8/Jerry_(3).jpg"]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"0.jpg"]];
    cell.catlabel.text = [[recipes valueForKey:@"name"]objectAtIndex:0];
    return cell;
}
else
{
Cell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT4RNUL18GXdQt2h9Ay4e7eHwm1lgC1BiRKrZY72Apt7b9cTViR7Q"]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"0.jpg"]];
    cell.label.text = [[recipes valueForKey:@"name"]objectAtIndex:0];
return cell;
} }
```

THE above code is running but it works only for one collection view i have debug this using breakpoint so it goes into first return statement. so another part of the code is not even running.so how to solve this problem.
thank you in advance :)

Comment: Did you find anything, I am having the same problem right now :(

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure both collection view is setting the right delegate and datasource.
2. Use NSLog to find out where is the problem or which part is missing.

   ```
    -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:        (NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
   {  
       NSLog(@"%d collection view is asking cell",cv.tag);
       if (_collectionview.tag==2) {
           Cell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
           [cell.image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.104:808/Images/Image1.jpg"]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"0.jpg"]];
           cell.label.text = [[recipes valueForKey:@"name"]objectAtIndex:0];
           return cell;
       }

       if(_collectionview.tag==1)
       {
           Cell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:jerryCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
           [cell.image1 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20121123214954/tomandjerry/images/a/a8/Jerry_(3).jpg"]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"0.jpg"]];
           cell.catlabel.text = [[recipes valueForKey:@"name"]objectAtIndex:0];
           return cell;
       }else{
           Cell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
           [cell.image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT4RNUL18GXdQt2h9Ay4e7eHwm1lgC1BiRKrZY72Apt7b9cTViR7Q"]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"0.jpg"]];
           cell.label.text = [[recipes valueForKey:@"name"]objectAtIndex:0];
           return cell;
       } 
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is you are using `"_collectionView"` which is maybe some global UICollectionView property but this delegate method return `"cv"`of type UICollectionView.

Use `cv` instead of `_collectionView`. Following code work perfect !!

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
 {  

if (cv.tag==2) {


Cell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];


 [cell.image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.104:808/Images/Image1.jpg"]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"0.jpg"]];
    cell.label.text = [[recipes valueForKey:@"name"]objectAtIndex:0];


return cell;

}

if(cv.tag==1)
{
    Cell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:jerryCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];


    [cell.image1 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20121123214954/tomandjerry/images/a/a8/Jerry_(3).jpg"]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"0.jpg"]];
    cell.catlabel.text = [[recipes valueForKey:@"name"]objectAtIndex:0];
    return cell;
}
else
{
Cell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT4RNUL18GXdQt2h9Ay4e7eHwm1lgC1BiRKrZY72Apt7b9cTViR7Q"]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"0.jpg"]];
    cell.label.text = [[recipes valueForKey:@"name"]objectAtIndex:0];
return cell;
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the collectionView instance obtained in the delegate or datasource always. So in your case instead of using properties use `cv.tag`. `_collectionView` is a property (IBOutlet perhaps) and it always refers to one (hopefully) of your collection views.

To make your code more clean, I would suggest to have separate classes which would act as delegate/datasource for your collection view. So in your view controller set the collection views delegate to that separate class instead of `self`. It would be easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Try Following Code :

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{  
    Cell *cell;

    if (collectionView.tag==2) 
    {
        cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell.image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.104:808/Images/Image1.jpg"]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"0.jpg"]];
        cell.label.text = [[recipes valueForKey:@"name"]objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    if(collectionView.tag==1)
    {
        cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:jerryCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell.image1 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20121123214954/tomandjerry/images/a/a8/Jerry_(3).jpg"]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"0.jpg"]];
        cell.catlabel.text = [[recipes valueForKey:@"name"]objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    else
    {
        cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell.image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT4RNUL18GXdQt2h9Ay4e7eHwm1lgC1BiRKrZY72Apt7b9cTViR7Q"]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"0.jpg"]];
        cell.label.text = [[recipes valueForKey:@"name"]objectAtIndex:0];
     } 

    return cell;
}
```

This code it works for you.

Comment: in this if the first if condition will execute than the other one will not and i want that all condition should be checked ones

Comment: this code is generating same problem if it goes into first if statement and than it goes in to second if so the effect on the identifier Cell will only be of 2nd if condition it means that only "http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20121123214954/tomandjerry/images/a/a8/Jerry_(3).jpg" this image will be shown.